# Prove or disprove: If $f^*$ is surjective, then $f$ is surjective.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $K$ be a field, $V,W$ vector spaces over $K$ and $$f: V \rightarrow W$$
Then let $$f^*: W^* \rightarrow V^*$$ $$ \beta \mapsto \beta \circ f$$ Prove or disprove that if $f^*$ is surjective, then $f$ is surjective.

I have got a clue that this is wrong, but I cannot express the surjectivity of $f^*$ in any helpful way. Any hints or explainations welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you *can* prove is that if $f^*$ is surjective, then $f$ is injective.

But consider $f\colon\Bbb R\hookrightarrow \Bbb R^2$, $f(x) = (x,0)$. Then $f^*$ is certainly surjective. (Let $e_1,e_2$ be the standard basis for $\Bbb R^2$, $e_1^*, e_2^*$ the dual basis. Then $f^*(e_1^*)(t) = e_1^*(f(t)) = e_1^*((t,0)) = t = \phi(t)$ for $\phi$ the obvious basis element of $\Bbb R^*$.)

Comment: The proof you are suggesting was among the proofs I did, I found this one problematic because I could not imagine what it means for $f^*$ to be surjective. Thank you.

Comment: You're most welcome. :)